# How to update or show my label faster? (Using Timer tick, interval 1 ms is too slow)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to generate a random number and show it with a label, the label decreases or increases one by one (till reaching or becoming the random number), I'm using a Timer tick for it and the interval of it is 1 ms, but, for example, if a number increases from 10 to 500, it just takes too long, like 5-6 seconds. I want it to "run" or "increase/decrease" really fast but the interval of 1 ms seems like the minimum value... Any way or idea to show my label increasing/decreasing faster? Thanks.

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Number = int.Parse(lblResult.Text);
    if (int.Parse(lblResult.Text) < RandomNumber)
    {
        lblResult.Text = (Number+1).ToString();
    }

    if (int.Parse(lblResult.Text) > RandomNumber)
    {               
        lblResult.Text = (Number-1).ToString();               
    }
}
```

Comment: Why parse the same string three times?  The fastest a WinForm Timer will run is about 16 ms.  The posted code does not explain the 5-6 seconds wait.  You have something else going on.

Comment: @LarsTech based only on your comment, actually it explain it exactly 16ms * 500 = 8s. But as you know windows clock is not prefect, and this time will probably warry a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Show it increasing/decreasing not by 1, but by 10 or 100. This way, it will look like it's faster. Actually, you can even calculate the value of this step dynamically.

Comment: oh ok, I got it now.

Comment: Using 10 or 100 will mean the last one or 2 digits will not change. Maybe use 13 or 132 or something so that the last 1 or 2 digits change also.